# Can't identify index of array - python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, indexing

I have a .mat file with embedded directories. There is data in each part that I've been accessing like this:

filemat['data'][0][0][number]

I've been able to use the number to access the specific file I want but sometimes it's in the wrong spot. However, I know there are labels on the mat file so I want to find the proper indexed position. How can I find the indexed position of the labels like RKneeMoment.

When looking at the array using the command, filemat['data']:

```
array([[(array([[  94.22346 ,  -59.518696, 2057.104   ],
               [  95.22453 ,  -59.142654, 2056.981   ],
               [  96.28398 ,  -58.748417, 2056.876   ],
               ...,
               [  69.30227 ,  139.07237 , 1622.3939  ],
               [  70.00589 ,  138.06749 , 1623.236   ],
               [  70.71416 ,  137.09174 , 1623.8989  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-119.25298 ,   35.997322,  173.61601 ],
               [-119.23584 ,   36.03106 ,  173.61818 ],
               [-119.22115 ,   36.067646,  173.61317 ],
               ...,
               [-120.11003 ,   35.33002 ,  173.07265 ],
               [-120.075516,   35.37947 ,  173.06596 ],
               [-120.06844 ,   35.39059 ,  173.06462 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-120.05633 ,   35.995853, -156.22377 ],
               [-120.1262  ,   35.95223 , -156.23819 ],
               [-120.21585 ,   35.902508, -156.2572  ],
               ...,
               [-115.86406 ,   39.534893, -156.01126 ],
               [-115.900536,   39.5411  , -155.96106 ],
               [-115.91077 ,   39.5414  , -155.94933 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 2.4424907e-15, -8.8817842e-16, -1.4329385e+02],
               [ 1.1102230e-15, -8.8817842e-16, -1.4325682e+02],
               [-2.4424907e-15,  8.8817842e-16, -1.4321346e+02],
               ...,
               [-8.8817842e-16,  0.0000000e+00, -1.3971187e+02],
               [ 2.2204460e-15,  0.0000000e+00, -1.3972438e+02],
               [ 4.4408921e-16, -3.5527137e-15, -1.3972780e+02]], dtype=float32), array([[-28.061281,  47.895683,  80.32273 ],
               [-28.068552,  47.937023,  80.3434  ],
               [-28.086166,  47.98929 ,  80.3557  ],
               ...,
               [-17.208565,  44.764164,  90.54468 ],
               [-17.122677,  44.796177,  90.57717 ],
               [-17.10097 ,  44.80397 ,  90.58376 ]], dtype=float32), array([[  59.160366, -169.43611 ,   71.90884 ],
               [  59.165825, -169.4162  ,   71.899055],
               [  59.160763, -169.39354 ,   71.88487 ],
               ...,
               [  66.32614 , -180.51631 ,   69.22071 ],
               [  66.21056 , -180.54091 ,   69.31192 ],
               [  66.18151 , -180.54613 ,   69.331764]], dtype=float32), array([[ -26.326773, -177.79337 ,   84.36151 ],
               [ -26.305866, -177.7842  ,   84.3809  ],
               [ -26.296648, -177.76532 ,   84.39732 ],
               ...,
               [ -18.025372, -188.58305 ,   89.3179  ],
               [ -18.131653, -188.55125 ,   89.42065 ],
               [ -18.157938, -188.54286 ,   89.444786]], dtype=float32), array([[ -20.690832, -253.6587  ,   72.37499 ],
               [ -20.6515  , -253.62743 ,   72.39149 ],
               [ -20.61149 , -253.58882 ,   72.403755],
               ...,
               [ -12.652351, -264.9621  ,   77.88845 ],
               [ -12.773672, -264.91238 ,   78.011246],
               [ -12.802934, -264.89966 ,   78.03964 ]], dtype=float32), array([[  69.074066, -249.85692 ,   54.853424],
               [  69.102234, -249.83044 ,   54.813847],
               [  69.12723 , -249.79948 ,   54.76875 ],
               ...,
               [  77.097595, -259.61603 ,   50.04263 ],
               [  76.97082 , -259.62238 ,   50.10537 ],
               [  76.93863 , -259.6232  ,   50.119045]], dtype=float32), array([[ 8.8817842e-16, -3.9047040e+02,  6.5491608e+01],
               [ 1.7763568e-15, -3.9044400e+02,  6.5492714e+01],
               [ 8.8817842e-16, -3.9041855e+02,  6.5496185e+01],
               ...,
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -3.9913074e+02,  6.5873795e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -3.9908542e+02,  6.5921188e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.9907297e+02,  6.5932083e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.7763568e-15, -4.1744412e+02, -6.5491608e+01],
               [ 8.8817842e-16, -4.1741873e+02, -6.5492714e+01],
               [-1.7763568e-15, -4.1739066e+02, -6.5496185e+01],
               ...,
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -4.2293161e+02, -6.5873795e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -4.2288223e+02, -6.5921188e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -4.2286951e+02, -6.5932083e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[  5.893143,  24.717182, -81.01072 ],
               [  5.825471,  24.658766, -81.04215 ],
               [  5.748879,  24.587626, -81.09527 ],
               ...,
               [ 17.353804,  14.60318 , -85.544044],
               [ 17.305853,  14.703374, -85.45829 ],
               [ 17.293354,  14.727834, -85.43745 ]], dtype=float32), array([[109.50947  , -82.93747  , -16.10404  ],
               [109.52491  , -82.93336  , -16.050556 ],
               [109.531654 , -82.9315   , -15.998026 ],
               ...,
               [103.79013  , -93.180176 , -14.5796175],
               [103.76689  , -93.053345 , -14.526529 ],
               [103.76184  , -93.02237  , -14.512229 ]], dtype=float32), array([[  3.8300564, -79.76868  , -90.194534 ],
               [  3.7565222, -79.82632  , -90.22021  ],
               [  3.659024 , -79.89578  , -90.25452  ],
               ...,
               [  3.0124176, -92.104675 , -91.64128  ],
               [  2.9345767, -92.03166  , -91.62906  ],
               [  2.915719 , -92.01307  , -91.62369  ]], dtype=float32), array([[   6.7437286, -193.70683  ,  -78.310936 ],
               [   6.6996517, -193.75856  ,  -78.30494  ],
               [   6.644401 , -193.81934  ,  -78.304245 ],
               ...,
               [   5.949691 , -204.57176  ,  -77.30013  ],
               [   5.8726196, -204.44284  ,  -77.25613  ],
               [   5.855483 , -204.41127  ,  -77.24612  ]], dtype=float32), array([[  94.7161   , -251.48973  ,    1.2275972],
               [  94.69268  , -251.49702  ,    1.2423354],
               [  94.6603   , -251.50502  ,    1.2544038],
               ...,
               [  99.28653  , -259.62024  ,   -1.1443292],
               [  99.180336 , -259.5225   ,   -1.0332767],
               [  99.15533  , -259.49805  ,   -1.007286 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-1.7763568e-15, -3.6958716e+02, -6.2973938e+01],
               [ 1.7763568e-15, -3.6961612e+02, -6.2977722e+01],
               [ 1.7763568e-15, -3.6964682e+02, -6.2985554e+01],
               ...,
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.7909631e+02, -6.1617924e+01],
               [-7.1054274e-15, -3.7899899e+02, -6.1629803e+01],
               [-1.4210855e-14, -3.7897443e+02, -6.1633015e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.0000000e+00, -4.1608179e+02,  6.2973938e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -4.1610043e+02,  6.2977722e+01],
               [ 3.5527137e-15, -4.1612247e+02,  6.2985554e+01],
               ...,
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -4.2575259e+02,  6.1617924e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -4.2570779e+02,  6.1629803e+01],
               [-7.1054274e-15, -4.2569391e+02,  6.1633015e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[  45.577282, -176.08495 ,   43.552383],
               [  45.61259 , -176.09018 ,   43.549286],
               [  45.680332, -176.08109 ,   43.549015],
               ...,
               [  42.539825, -175.28908 ,   44.28433 ],
               [  42.79338 , -175.251   ,   44.38181 ],
               [  43.40782 , -175.13171 ,   44.301453]], dtype=float32), array([[ -32.098698, -181.10039 ,   67.40611 ],
               [ -32.037746, -181.09567 ,   67.39432 ],
               [ -31.932545, -181.09286 ,   67.373566],
               ...,
               [ -35.25076 , -177.68874 ,   67.22636 ],
               [ -35.062523, -177.82358 ,   67.11846 ],
               [ -34.44448 , -177.99612 ,   67.0219  ]], dtype=float32), array([[ -48.76983 , -254.51529 ,   38.806396],
               [ -48.755756, -254.5191  ,   38.81471 ],
               [ -48.692394, -254.53159 ,   38.815258],
               ...,
               [ -52.88757 , -250.3951  ,   34.145557],
               [ -52.49531 , -250.59172 ,   33.91683 ],
               [ -51.620926, -250.81566 ,   33.76435 ]], dtype=float32), array([[  36.050278, -229.55637 ,   46.324333],
               [  36.071083, -229.56033 ,   46.31624 ],
               [  36.13236 , -229.55415 ,   46.30649 ],
               ...,
               [  31.543295, -227.25092 ,   45.45678 ],
               [  31.865791, -227.25586 ,   45.50529 ],
               [  32.65675 , -227.18126 ,   45.39119 ]], dtype=float32), array([[  -1.4465388, -368.09164  ,   42.917526 ],
               [  -1.4385492, -368.08017  ,   42.91149  ],
               [  -1.3676718, -368.0605   ,   42.90099  ],
               ...,
               [  -2.92798  , -370.61554  ,   42.995026 ],
               [  -2.373797 , -370.76187  ,   42.824978 ],
               [  -1.0906446, -370.82248  ,   42.605003 ]], dtype=float32), array([[   1.4465388, -353.2602   ,  -42.917526 ],
               [   1.4385492, -353.2453   ,  -42.91149  ],
               [   1.3676718, -353.18344  ,  -42.90099  ],
               ...,
               [   2.92798  , -357.41965  ,  -42.995026 ],
               [   2.373797 , -357.41083  ,  -42.824978 ],
               [   1.0906446, -357.00455  ,  -42.605003 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 52.217834, -92.0806  , -27.255945],
               [ 52.274174, -92.06737 , -27.264252],
               [ 52.335022, -92.060715, -27.256638],
               ...,
               [ 61.878517, -90.2997  , -24.235346],
               [ 61.873688, -90.283615, -24.28709 ],
               [ 61.954376, -90.21463 , -24.334255]], dtype=float32), array([[-27.276894, -57.138752, -74.68163 ],
               [-27.106182, -56.995377, -74.58138 ],
               [-27.006203, -56.932888, -74.5521  ],
               ...,
               [-16.158808, -54.46472 , -75.56983 ],
               [-17.828548, -54.409237, -75.62415 ],
               [-20.1371  , -54.507145, -75.291214]], dtype=float32), array([[ -46.278236, -216.32019 ,  -57.778885],
               [ -46.24664 , -216.31631 ,  -57.8243  ],
               [ -46.211594, -216.31998 ,  -57.844105],
               ...,
               [ -36.364677, -216.16197 ,  -57.858074],
               [ -36.21891 , -216.26505 ,  -57.87992 ],
               [ -35.98853 , -216.29048 ,  -58.007595]], dtype=float32), array([[  30.667719, -238.57747 ,  -42.98068 ],
               [  30.688704, -238.57954 ,  -42.996925],
               [  30.708746, -238.59044 ,  -42.977238],
               ...,
               [  38.307167, -236.42265 ,  -39.1314  ],
               [  38.49566 , -236.44789 ,  -39.172737],
               [  38.749073, -236.40102 ,  -39.298244]], dtype=float32), array([[-2.6794167e+00, -3.7428162e+02, -4.1384853e+01],
               [-2.6593752e+00, -3.7429141e+02, -4.1423790e+01],
               [-2.6388657e+00, -3.7431290e+02, -4.1414169e+01],
               ...,
               [-2.2096781e-01, -3.7224939e+02, -4.1642448e+01],
               [ 1.3719244e-01, -3.7234561e+02, -4.1713638e+01],
               [ 5.4540789e-01, -3.7234738e+02, -4.1927181e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 2.6794167e+00, -3.5792596e+02,  4.1384853e+01],
               [ 2.6593752e+00, -3.5789117e+02,  4.1423790e+01],
               [ 2.6388657e+00, -3.5796307e+02,  4.1414169e+01],
               ...,
               [ 2.2096781e-01, -3.5721204e+02,  4.1642448e+01],
               [-1.3719244e-01, -3.5761081e+02,  4.1713638e+01],
               [-5.4540789e-01, -3.5778671e+02,  4.1927181e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[-50.855793 , -48.56817  ,  -6.9462113],
               [-50.832806 , -48.58775  ,  -6.959189 ],
               [-50.72542  , -48.643967 ,  -6.984593 ],
               ...,
               [-44.86524  , -58.296635 , -12.971666 ],
               [-44.065395 , -58.364307 , -13.317304 ],
               [-42.59092  , -58.69432  , -13.586066 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.6995477e+02, -1.8587938e+01, -1.2458640e+01],
               [ 1.6997711e+02, -1.8552261e+01, -1.2422521e+01],
               [ 1.7007253e+02, -1.8488758e+01, -1.2363195e+01],
               ...,
               [ 1.6291283e+02,  1.9267855e+01, -7.6270171e-02],
               [ 1.6364552e+02,  1.9301601e+01,  3.3340704e-01],
               [ 1.6487248e+02,  1.9619001e+01,  1.9244993e-01]], dtype=float32), array([[143.77577  , -31.662676 ,  60.533745 ],
               [143.7916   , -31.617668 ,  60.550606 ],
               [143.88307  , -31.550076 ,  60.572704 ],
               ...,
               [138.2205   ,  -8.20373  ,  68.75179  ],
               [138.71869  ,  -8.169915 ,  69.0806   ],
               [140.00308  ,  -7.9615254,  68.91759  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-63.940437 , -41.643055 ,  -8.772245 ],
               [-63.926056 , -41.682365 ,  -8.837195 ],
               [-63.91684  , -41.670994 ,  -8.849888 ],
               ...,
               [-52.007664 , -54.71631  ,  -4.1749916],
               [-51.592216 , -54.608353 ,  -4.2557735],
               [-51.138344 , -54.5948   ,  -4.5068674]], dtype=float32), array([[160.43953 , -28.801718,  28.931822],
               [160.4479  , -28.762243,  28.91747 ],
               [160.45319 , -28.64205 ,  28.973368],
               ...,
               [159.3846  ,  22.20294 ,  13.065506],
               [159.73979 ,  22.449638,  12.985045],
               [160.11086 ,  22.665117,  12.816837]], dtype=float32), array([[147.0593   , -44.589764 , -34.57327  ],
               [147.07549  , -44.58425  , -34.589188 ],
               [147.09135  , -44.521004 , -34.53663  ],
               ...,
               [147.76749  ,  -6.05507  , -45.7292   ],
               [148.12288  ,  -5.78367  , -45.803528 ],
               [148.52953  ,  -5.5406265, -45.987778 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 84.73535  , 106.386734 ,  -5.703525 ],
               [ 84.76968  , 106.364395 ,  -5.6089272],
               [ 84.79154  , 106.35189  ,  -5.514692 ],
               ...,
               [131.82317  ,  33.622654 ,   4.750332 ],
               [131.80359  ,  33.690937 ,   4.826278 ],
               [131.79854  ,  33.708527 ,   4.84386  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-12.105049  , -15.198105  ,   0.8147893 ],
               [-12.109953  , -15.194913  ,   0.8012754 ],
               [-12.113076  , -15.193127  ,   0.7878132 ],
               ...,
               [-18.83188   ,  -4.803236  ,  -0.67861885],
               [-18.829082  ,  -4.8129907 ,  -0.6894683 ],
               [-18.828362  ,  -4.815504  ,  -0.69198   ]], dtype=float32), array([[   3.263759 , -238.37267  ,   -8.95338  ],
               [   3.196051 , -238.35475  ,   -9.073521 ],
               [   3.1578133, -238.3362   ,   -9.178413 ],
               ...,
               [-140.65965  , -191.87556  ,    4.750332 ],
               [-140.55772  , -191.91876  ,    4.826278 ],
               [-140.53064  , -191.92935  ,    4.84386  ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 198.28131,  -32.67676,  -96.27773],
               [ 198.23624,  -32.62596,  -96.3295 ],
               [ 198.20338,  -32.55174,  -96.37172],
               ...,
               [ 149.79938, -166.98169,  -59.75516],
               [ 149.94731, -166.9047 ,  -59.57191],
               [ 149.98404, -166.88467,  -59.52933]], dtype=float32), array([[ 209.84898 ,  -21.358925,   31.30101 ],
               [ 209.80772 ,  -21.318825,   31.265774],
               [ 209.77318 ,  -21.249525,   31.2582  ],
               ...,
               [ 153.53873 , -140.66492 ,   72.76126 ],
               [ 153.48238 , -140.45876 ,   72.950676],
               [ 153.47063 , -140.40813 ,   72.99508 ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 6.9366539e+01,  1.4790142e+03,  4.0646443e+00],
               [ 6.9463669e+01,  1.4790901e+03,  4.2658691e+00],
               [ 6.9520645e+01,  1.4791953e+03,  4.4515338e+00],
               ...,
               [ 2.5365094e+02,  9.0117987e+02, -6.7861885e-01],
               [ 2.5353220e+02,  9.0162134e+02, -6.8946832e-01],
               [ 2.5350082e+02,  9.0172681e+02, -6.9198000e-01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 3.5527137e-15, -3.8439166e+02, -4.3514637e+01],
               [ 3.5527137e-15, -3.8438608e+02, -4.3514782e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.8437469e+02, -4.3509216e+01],
               ...,
               [-1.4210855e-14, -3.9257092e+02, -4.2594795e+01],
               [ 1.4210855e-14, -3.9250909e+02, -4.2606449e+01],
               [-1.4210855e-14, -3.9249472e+02, -4.2609257e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.0000000e+00, -4.0388739e+02,  4.3514637e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -4.0389474e+02,  4.3514782e+01],
               [-3.5527137e-15, -4.0389789e+02,  4.3509216e+01],
               ...,
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -4.0982120e+02,  4.2594795e+01],
               [ 1.4210855e-14, -4.0976788e+02,  4.2606449e+01],
               [-1.4210855e-14, -4.0975583e+02,  4.2609257e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.0000000e+00, -3.8411337e+02, -4.5610504e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.8412582e+02, -4.5617077e+01],
               [-7.1054274e-15, -3.8413525e+02, -4.5623478e+01],
               ...,
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -3.9507516e+02, -4.5770111e+01],
               [ 2.1316282e-14, -3.9504330e+02, -4.5772480e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.9503540e+02, -4.5773083e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[-7.1054274e-15, -3.9895499e+02,  4.5610504e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -3.9899109e+02,  4.5617077e+01],
               [-7.1054274e-15, -3.9903061e+02,  4.5623478e+01],
               ...,
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -3.9093875e+02,  4.5770111e+01],
               [ 1.4210855e-14, -3.9094461e+02,  4.5772480e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -3.9094595e+02,  4.5773083e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[  -5.9627833, -141.39037  ,  -23.359749 ],
               [  -5.9575357, -141.35922  ,  -23.38692  ],
               [  -5.9447536, -141.31543  ,  -23.423176 ],
               ...,
               [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       ],
               [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       ],
               [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       ]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.0000000e+00, -2.5251561e+02,  3.9365444e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -2.5249016e+02,  3.9362778e+01],
               [-1.4210855e-14, -2.5244925e+02,  3.9364834e+01],
               ...,
               [ 1.7763568e-14, -2.4634981e+02,  3.7735863e+01],
               [-3.5527137e-15, -2.4635220e+02,  3.7730053e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -2.4635252e+02,  3.7728706e+01]], dtype=float32), array([[ 0.0000000e+00, -2.4880470e+02, -3.9365444e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -2.4878885e+02, -3.9362778e+01],
               [-1.4210855e-14, -2.4876300e+02, -3.9364834e+01],
               ...,
               [ 2.1316282e-14, -2.3541389e+02, -3.7735863e+01],
               [ 7.1054274e-15, -2.3541560e+02, -3.7730053e+01],
               [ 0.0000000e+00, -2.3541614e+02, -3.7728706e+01]], dtype=float32), array(['mm'], dtype='<U2'), array(['N'], dtype='<U1'), array(['Nmm'], dtype='<U3'), array([[200.]], dtype=float32), array([[1]], dtype=uint8), array([[543]], dtype=uint16), array(['iAA02'], dtype='<U5'), array(['CBRUCluster'], dtype='<U11'))]],
      dtype=[('HeadO', 'O'), ('HeadA', 'O'), ('HeadL', 'O'), ('HeadP', 'O'), ('Left_FAO', 'O'), ('Left_FAA', 'O'), ('Left_FAL', 'O'), ('Left_FAP', 'O'), ('Left_FootO', 'O'), ('Left_FootA', 'O'), ('Left_FootL', 'O'), ('Left_FootP', 'O'), ('Left_ShankO', 'O'), ('Left_ShankA', 'O'), ('Left_ShankL', 'O'), ('Left_ShankP', 'O'), ('Left_ThighO', 'O'), ('Left_ThighA', 'O'), ('Left_ThighL', 'O'), ('Left_ThighP', 'O'), ('Left_UAO', 'O'), ('Left_UAA', 'O'), ('Left_UAL', 'O'), ('Left_UAP', 'O'), ('PelvisO', 'O'), ('PelvisA', 'O'), ('PelvisL', 'O'), ('PelvisP', 'O'), ('Right_FAO', 'O'), ('Right_FAA', 'O'), ('Right_FAL', 'O'), ('Right_FAP', 'O'), ('Right_FootO', 'O'), ('Right_FootA', 'O'), ('Right_FootL', 'O'), ('Right_FootP', 'O'), ('Right_ShankO', 'O'), ('Right_ShankA', 'O'), ('Right_ShankL', 'O'), ('Right_ShankP', 'O'), ('Right_ThighO', 'O'), ('Right_ThighA', 'O'), ('Right_ThighL', 'O'), ('Right_ThighP', 'O'), ('Right_UAO', 'O'), ('Right_UAA', 'O'), ('Right_UAL', 'O'), ('Right_UAP', 'O'), ('TrunkO', 'O'), ('TrunkA', 'O'), ('TrunkL', 'O'), ('TrunkP', 'O'), ('RFHD', 'O'), ('RBHD', 'O'), ('LBHD', 'O'), ('LFHD', 'O'), ('SN', 'O'), ('XP', 'O'), ('C7', 'O'), ('RSCAP', 'O'), ('LSCAP', 'O'), ('LBUR', 'O'), ('LBLR', 'O'), ('LBLL', 'O'), ('LBUL', 'O'), ('RAC', 'O'), ('RUAPA', 'O'), ('RUAPP', 'O'), ('RUADP', 'O'), ('RELBL', 'O'), ('RELBM', 'O'), ('RFAPA', 'O'), ('RFAPP', 'O'), ('RFADP', 'O'), ('RFADA', 'O'), ('RRAD', 'O'), ('RULN', 'O'), ('RHAND', 'O'), ('LAC', 'O'), ('LUAPA', 'O'), ('LUAPP', 'O'), ('LUADP', 'O'), ('LELBL', 'O'), ('LELBM', 'O'), ('LFAPA', 'O'), ('LFAPP', 'O'), ('LFADP', 'O'), ('LHAND', 'O'), ('RASI', 'O'), ('RIC', 'O'), ('PVUR', 'O'), ('PVLR', 'O'), ('PVLL', 'O'), ('PVUL', 'O'), ('LIC', 'O'), ('LASI', 'O'), ('RGT', 'O'), ('RTHPA', 'O'), ('RTHPP', 'O'), ('RTHDP', 'O'), ('RTHDA', 'O'), ('RKNL', 'O'), ('RKNM', 'O'), ('RSHPA', 'O'), ('RSHPP', 'O'), ('RSHDP', 'O'), ('RSHDA', 'O'), ('RANL', 'O'), ('RHEE', 'O'), ('RM1', 'O'), ('RM5', 'O'), ('LGT', 'O'), ('LTHPA', 'O'), ('LTHPP', 'O'), ('LTHDP', 'O'), ('LTHDA', 'O'), ('LKNL', 'O'), ('LKNM', 'O'), ('LSHPA', 'O'), ('LSHDP', 'O'), ('LSHDA', 'O'), ('LANL', 'O'), ('LHEE', 'O'), ('LM1', 'O'), ('LM5', 'O'), ('U_125', 'O'), ('U_126', 'O'), ('LPelvisAngles', 'O'), ('RPelvisAngles', 'O'), ('LHipAngles', 'O'), ('RHipAngles', 'O'), ('LKneeAngles', 'O'), ('RKneeAngles', 'O'), ('LAnkleAngles', 'O'), ('RAnkleAngles', 'O'), ('F_ForcePlate1', 'O'), ('F_ForcePlate2', 'O'), ('F_ForcePlate3', 'O'), ('F_ForcePlate4', 'O'), ('LHipForce', 'O'), ('RHipForce', 'O'), ('LKneeForce', 'O'), ('RKneeForce', 'O'), ('LAnkleForce', 'O'), ('RAnkleForce', 'O'), ('LHipMoment', 'O'), ('RHipMoment', 'O'), ('LKneeMoment', 'O'), ('RKneeMoment', 'O'), ('LAnkleMoment', 'O'), ('RAnkleMoment', 'O'), ('LSagSumMoment', 'O'), ('RSagSumMoment', 'O'), ('RANM', 'O'), ('LANM', 'O'), ('LSHPP', 'O'), ('Pelvis_Right_Thigh_score', 'O'), ('Right_Thigh_Right_Shank_score', 'O'), ('Right_Thigh_Right_Shank_sara', 'O'), ('Right_Shank_Right_Foot_score', 'O'), ('Pelvis_Left_Thigh_score', 'O'), ('Left_Thigh_Left_Shank_score', 'O'), ('Left_Thigh_Left_Shank_sara', 'O'), ('Left_Shank_Left_Foot_score', 'O'), ('Pelvis_Trunk_score', 'O'), ('Trunk_Head_score', 'O'), ('Trunk_Right_UA_score', 'O'), ('Right_UA_Right_FA_score', 'O'), ('Right_UA_Right_FA_sara', 'O'), ('Trunk_Left_UA_score', 'O'), ('Left_UA_Left_FA_score', 'O'), ('Left_UA_Left_FA_sara', 'O'), ('OGlobalSystem', 'O'), ('XGlobalSystem', 'O'), ('YGlobalSystem', 'O'), ('ZGlobalSystem', 'O'), ('OPelvisLC', 'O'), ('XPelvisLC', 'O'), ('YPelvisLC', 'O'), ('ZPelvisLC', 'O'), ('PELOrigin', 'O'), ('LASI_v', 'O'), ('RASI_v', 'O'), ('SACR', 'O'), ('RASI_residuals', 'O'), ('LASI_residuals', 'O'), ('LHJC', 'O'), ('RHJC', 'O'), ('LKJC', 'O'), ('RKJC', 'O'), ('LKNM_v', 'O'), ('LKNL_v', 'O'), ('RKNM_v', 'O'), ('RKNL_v', 'O'), ('LKNM_residuals', 'O'), ('LKNL_residuals', 'O'), ('RKNM_residuals', 'O'), ('RKNL_residuals', 'O'), ('OLeftFemurLC', 'O'), ('XLeftFemurLC', 'O'), ('YLeftFemurLC', 'O'), ('ZLeftFemurLC', 'O'), ('ORightFemurLC', 'O'), ('XRightFemurLC', 'O'), ('YRightFemurLC', 'O'), ('ZRightFemurLC', 'O'), ('LAJC', 'O'), ('RAJC', 'O'), ('LANM_v', 'O'), ('LANL_v', 'O'), ('RANM_v', 'O'), ('RANL_v', 'O'), ('LANM_residuals', 'O'), ('LANL_residuals', 'O'), ('RANM_residuals', 'O'), ('RANL_residuals', 'O'), ('OLeftTibiaLC', 'O'), ('XLeftTibiaLC', 'O'), ('YLeftTibiaLC', 'O'), ('ZLeftTibiaLC', 'O'), ('ORightTibiaLC', 'O'), ('XRightTibiaLC', 'O'), ('YRightTibiaLC', 'O'), ('ZRightTibiaLC', 'O'), ('OLeftFootLC', 'O'), ('XLeftFootLC', 'O'), ('YLeftFootLC', 'O'), ('ZLeftFootLC', 'O'), ('ORightFootLC', 'O'), ('XRightFootLC', 'O'), ('YRightFootLC', 'O'), ('ZRightFootLC', 'O'), ('P_ForcePlate1', 'O'), ('P_ForcePlate2', 'O'), ('P_ForcePlate3', 'O'), ('P_ForcePlate4', 'O'), ('o_PVUL', 'O'), ('o_PVLL', 'O'), ('o_PVLR', 'O'), ('o_PVUR', 'O'), ('o_RASI', 'O'), ('o_RIC', 'O'), ('o_LIC', 'O'), ('o_LASI', 'O'), ('o_RGT', 'O'), ('o_RTHPA', 'O'), ('o_RTHPP', 'O'), ('o_RTHDP', 'O'), ('o_RTHDA', 'O'), ('o_RKNL', 'O'), ('o_RKNM', 'O'), ('o_LGT', 'O'), ('o_LTHPA', 'O'), ('o_LTHPP', 'O'), ('o_LTHDP', 'O'), ('o_LTHDA', 'O'), ('o_LKNL', 'O'), ('o_LKNM', 'O'), ('o_RSHPA', 'O'), ('o_RSHPP', 'O'), ('o_RSHDP', 'O'), ('o_RSHDA', 'O'), ('o_RANL', 'O'), ('o_RANM', 'O'), ('o_LSHPA', 'O'), ('o_LSHPP', 'O'), ('o_LSHDP', 'O'), ('o_LSHDA', 'O'), ('o_LANL', 'O'), ('o_LANM', 'O'), ('o_RHEE', 'O'), ('o_RM1', 'O'), ('o_RM5', 'O'), ('o_LHEE', 'O'), ('o_LM1', 'O'), ('o_LM5', 'O'), ('o_C7', 'O'), ('o_SN', 'O'), ('o_XP', 'O'), ('o_RSCAP', 'O'), ('o_LSCAP', 'O'), ('o_LB', 'O'), ('o_LELBL', 'O'), ('o_LELBM', 'O'), ('o_RELBL', 'O'), ('o_RELBM', 'O'), ('o_RForeArm', 'O'), ('o_RRAD', 'O'), ('o_RULN', 'O'), ('units', 'O'), ('Force_units', 'O'), ('Moment_units', 'O'), ('Rate', 'O'), ('Start_Frame', 'O'), ('End_Frame', 'O'), ('Name', 'O'), ('Model', 'O')])
```

I've been able to use just indexed positions but I want to be able to actually grab the index using the value like RKneeMoment. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Can you share expected output

Comment: Hey Nguyen, I'd expect to be able to pull the index of 'RKneeMoment'. So something like filemat['data'][0].index('RKneeMoment')